# Unable to use title format from chunk after figure

Tags: r, formatting, r-markdown, chunks

I have tried the following R Markdown document (Word output):

```
cat("##Title 1", "\n")
cat("##Title 2", "\n")
```

This works fine, both lines are displayed as titles, however:

```
cat("##Title 1", "\n")
a=c(1,2,3)
b=c(2,2,5)
plot(a,b,type='l')
cat("##Title 2", "\n")
```

shows Title 1 properly, then the figure, but Title 2 appears as "##Title 2" without title formatting. Both chunks use options `'echo=FALSE'`and `results='asis'`

What am I doing wrong? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandoc` requires a blank line before the heading, c.f. https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#atx-style-headings. Use

```
cat("##Title 1", "\n")
a=c(1,2,3)
b=c(2,2,5)
plot(a,b,type='l')
cat("\n", "##Title 2", "\n")
```

instead.